# `nuxt` vs `nuxt generate`: require is not defined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm getting this error from a nuxt site built with `nuxt generate`

`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

It's happening in two files on this code:

````
```
vendor.js:  e.exports=require("vue")
app.js:     t.exports=require("core-js/library/fn/symbol/iterator")
```
````

When I preview the site with just `nuxt` it runs fine.

I ran into [this bug](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/438) so I'm using `webpack-node-externals` which I don't really understand.

````
```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  /* Headers of the page */
  head: {      },
  css: [      ],
  /* Build configuration */
  build: {
    extend (config, { isDev, isClient }) {
      if (isDev && isClient) {
        /* Run ESLint on save */
        config.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /(node_modules)/
        })
      } else {
        // https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/438
        config.externals = [ nodeExternals({
          whitelist: ['vue-videobg']
        })]
      }
    }
  },
  modules: [
    'nuxt-imagemin',
    ['nuxt-sass-resources-loader', [
      '@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss',
      '@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss',
      '@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_breakpoints.scss',
      '@/assets/bootstrap4/_variables.scss',
      '@/assets/variables.scss',
    ]],
    ['bootstrap-vue/nuxt', { css: false, }],
    ['@nuxtjs/google-analytics', {
      id: 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-6'
    }],
  ],
  plugins: [
    'plugins/bootstrap-vue.js',
    'plugins/scroll.js',
    { ssr: false, src: '~/plugins/startup.js', },
    { ssr: false, src: '~/plugins/ksvuescrollmagic.js', },
  ],
}
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Eh, this is a tumbleweed.  I fixed it using `isServer`:

`if (isServer) {
        // https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/438
        config.externals = [ nodeExternals({
          whitelist: ['vue-videobg']
        })]
      }`

Answer (score 0):

If you use Nuxt v.2.0, require is no more encouraged.
This what says the changelog of the 2.0 :
[Upgrade `nuxt.config.js`, `modules` and `serverMiddleware` to use `import/export` instead of `require`](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/releases/tag/v2.0.0)

Comment: How would one do that?